# Where is subsetOf in scala collections?

Tags: scala

I'm at a loss on this one...

Looking at a `Set` in [Scala collections](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Set.html), I see that there is a method called `subsetOf`. But when I try to find where it is in the actual .scala source code (I've looked in [Set.scala, GenSet.scala, SetLike.scala](https://github.com/scala/scala/tree/v2.9.2/src/library/scala/collection) etc...) I can't find it!!!

Which trait actually defines that method? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you click on function in scaladoc, you may see where is it defined:

[image]

Comment: What does it mean when it says stuff like `SeqLike -> GenSeqLike`?

Comment: @drozzy it probably means that method was introduced (e.g. declared) in GenSeqLike, but implemented/overriden in SeqLike (usually, for the reasons of performance), you may also see longer chains, like `List → SeqLike → GenSeqLike` for `+:` (introduced/declared in GenSeqLike, implemented in SeqLike, overriden in List`.

Comment: @drozzy it could mean that inheritance, from an implementaion point of view might have some benefits. But as you now experience its not that easy to see where that implemenations comes from. Try a IDE like eclipse it will redirect you to the definition class

Answer (score 2):

The scala API specifies:

> Definition Classes: GenSetLike

When you're looking at the API page, click the method entry to expand it.  You'll see more information, including the "Definition Classes".

If you look at the source for [GenSetLike.scala](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.9.2/src/library/scala/collection/GenSetLike.scala#L115), you'll see it:

```
def subsetOf(that: GenSet[A]): Boolean = this forall that
```

Comment: Great, thanks! That is a really weird trait... "A template trait for sets which may _possibly_ have their operations implemented in parallel." Haha, possibly implemented and possibly not!

Comment: @drozzy: It's a common supertrait for both traditional standard sequential collections and parallel collections. Therefore, they may possibly have their operations implemented in parallel, but it is not guaranteed that they are implemented in parallel, they might also be implemented as traditional sequential collection operations.